# Difference in iif statements

Tags: reporting-services

A hope someone can help:

What is the difference between this

```
=iif(Parameters!WhichReport.Value(0) = "Occupancy", False, True)
```

and this

```
=iif(Parameters!WhichReport.Value = "Occupancy", False, True)
```

Ta

Wayne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't T-SQL at all, if anything, this looks like an expression from SSRS, am I right?. If so, the difference between `Parameters!WhichReport.Value` and `Parameters!WhichReport.Value(0)` is that the first one is for single valued parameters (thus, it is the only value that can store), and the second expression is for multi valued parameters (in this case, the first value selected since is `Value(0)`).

Comment: Hi Lamak,  you are right it is a SSRS, sorry its a habit just typing in SQL/TSQL below. So what does the 0 represent, I know its a strange question but I don't know. I have a parameter that now allows multiple values but didn't yesterday and now the rpot doesn't work

Comment: @wafw1971 As I said, the `Value(0)` is referencing the first value of your multivalued parameter; `Value(1)` will reference the second value and so on. So, if your multi-valued parameter has, lets say, the values `10,11,12,13` selected, `Value(0)` will be `10`.

Comment: Sorry I thought I understood, but alas I don't. My multi Parameter is 
Select All, Occupancy, Pitch Nights Sold, Capcity
So if I want the parameter to sslect Occupancy I need to write the code like this   =iif(Parameters!WhichReport.Value(2) = "Occupancy", False, True)

Comment: @wafw1971 Not really, since it depends on the number of items selected by the user, so `Value(0)` is the first item selected, `Value(1)` the second, etc. If you want to know if one of your items was selected, you'll need to first create a string of all items and then look for the one you want, not really optimal. One approach would be something like this: `iif(InStr(Join(Parameters!p_myMultipleValueParameter.Value,","),"Occupancy")>0, False, True`

Answer (score 1):

The first works on the notion that the parameter passed in is an array of values. So `Value(0)` will retrieve the first item in the array, whereas the second statement works on the notion that there is **only one** item with that parameter named passed in.

As arrays are indexed based on a start of 0, `Value(0)` will return you the first item in the value array, whereas `Value(1)` would return the 2nd, and so on...